# Bootstrap 3 container shifting left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3.x i have two pages inside a container:

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      ...
      ...
   </div>
</body>
```

1. In the "Home" page the scroll bar is not present
2. In the "About" page the scroll bar is present

When i go from the Home to About page i see a content shifting to the left caused by the appearing of the scroll bar.

How can i prevent this annoying behaviour for the eyes? I must show always the scroll bar (also when is not necessary?)

Comment: Found a solution that show always a scrollbar: html {
 overflow-y: scroll; 
}

Answer (score 0):

You should check out your elements with your browser's inspector tool (right click and select **Inspect**). Hover over the elements in the inspector's code and see what elements are overflowing and causing the scroll bar to appear. Clicking the element will show you what CSS-styles it uses and you can fix the overflow by modifying the "live page" before doing it in your code. Fancy tool!

If you wish to receive more specific answer, we will need a bit more of your HTML code than that. Do you have any elements already added, like `.navbar` or so?

One of the known issues is that if `.navbar` is placed in a column like `.col-xs-8` it overflows, because the `.container` inside of the Bootstrap's navbar is set to fill the whole page width. Change it's CSS like following if you have the navbar in your page and see if it gets fixed:

```
.navbar-default .container { width: 100% !important; }
```

(Remove the `!important` if you notice it affects to something. Always better to avoid keeping those importants if they're not really necessary.